# How to put a condition on chained events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datepicker

I have three chained event like this:

```
$("#Id")
.click()
.focus()
.blur()
```

What I want:

```
var A = 0;
if(A == 0)
execute blur event
```

I want the blur event to get executed ONLY if a condition has been fullfilled.

I tried checking if the condition was fullfilled inside the blur event BUT the problem was that it executed the blur function which basicly did nothing but i still got a problem where i had to click two times to get the functionality i desierd from another event(NOTE: not the functionality from the blur event).

My main problem: 
I click on a textbox which shows me a datepicker and when i choose a date my blur event executes since i leave the textbox and choose a date from the datepicker. My blur event has a postback which executes but the problem is i dont want it to execute when im choosing dates from my datepicker. NOTE: When i choose a date i vae code that gets me the week from the date that i have choosen so it is not your deafult "datepicker" functionality, this is irrelevant to the question  but i thought it would be good to mention it.

If this is possible to do I deeply appreciate an answer. 
I any1 thinks of the following soloutions i just want to say ive tried and it did not work:
inside blur event:

```
return false
return true
```

Comment: What datepicker are you using and what code do you use to instantiate?

Comment: Im not exactly sure what your intention is, but is it something like this you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ZDzEw/

Comment: Im using the jquery UI datepicker. What im doing:
when i click on a textbox i get my datepicker, when i choose a date i get the week of that date BUT the problem is that i have a blur function that executes cuz im leaving the textbox and choosing a date. WHat i want: i want the blur only to execute if im not choosing a date. For this i have set options on my datepicker where i put the value to 0/1 depending if the datepicker has been opened or not but the problem is i cant figure out how to NOt execute the blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we all learn the hard way that when using a plugin it is good to read all of the documentation since it might actually include stuff that you might want to use for changes.

I read up on the jQuery datepicker in broader detail and learned that it has an `onClose` option that executes once you click out of the datepicker. So what I basically did was that I took the code from the `blur` function and put it in the `onClose` function(option) and voila.

Code:

```
        $('#calWeekF')
            .click(function () { this.select(); })
            .focus(function () { $('#calBtnShow').unbind('click', function () { $.overview.calendar.load() }); })  // De-activate button to prevent duplicate calls to loadCalendar
            .datepicker({
                showWeek: true,
                onSelect: function (date, object) {

                    $.MyProject.calendar.changeDate(new Date(date));

                    $.astra.calendar.changeWeek($("#" + object.id).val());
                    // Add some delay befor activating the button
                    $("#" + object.id).oneTime(200, 'calBtnShow', function () { $('#calBtnShow').click(function () { $.overview.calendar.load() }); });

                },
                onClose: function (date, object){
                    $.astra.calendar.changeWeek($("#" + object.id).val());
                    // Add some delay befor activating the button
                    $("#" + object.id).oneTime(200, 'calBtnShow', function () { $('#calBtnShow').click(function () { $.overview.calendar.load() }); });
                    }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method:

```
$('#Id').click().focus().filter(function() {
    // var A = 0;
    return (A==0);
}).blur();
```

Comment: Well when i tried this my datepicker stopped working as did my blur function. I dont get any error it simply does not execute. Sorry for the late reply but the weekend hit me:=)